Using Cloudflare transform rules to setup CSP but unable to iframe subdomain using apex domain contents
Looking for answers, have been going at this for awhile.
Using cloudflare and have setup CSP using transform rules.
I would like to iframe my apex domain 'domainA.com' into my subdomain 'sub.domainA.com'.
Generally CSP is working and only domains I specify is able to  iframe my content but when I try to iframe from my domainA.com into sub.domainA.com it doesn't seem to work.
Hope my explaination makes sense.
Help! TIA!
I have the following CF rules setup:
frame-ancestors 'self' https://domainA.com *.domainA.com;

